# How to show that a curve passes through the origin?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is given that the tangent to curve at points $x=1$ and $x=-1$ are perpendicular. I've managed to find the equation of the curve: y=$\frac{4}{3}x- \frac{5}{6}x^2$ but how do I show that the curve passes through the origin?

Comment: A curve will pass through a given point P$(h,k)$ if $x=h,y=k$ satisfy the given equation of the curve

Comment: $\frac43x-\frac56x^2$ is not an equation. There is no equals sign.

Comment: Please clarify equation is it $y = \dfrac{4}{3}x - \dfrac{5}{6}x^2$ or $y = \dfrac{4}{3x} - \dfrac{5}{6x^2}$?

Comment: @WarrenHill I'm pretty sure the first edit misplaced the curly braces in the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the equation is $y=\tfrac 43 x- \tfrac 56 x^2$.

A curve passes through the origin if the point $(0,0)$ satisfies the equation:

$$0 \overset{?}{=} \tfrac 43 (0)- \tfrac 56 (0)^2$$

Comment: My apologies, I forgot the y=...

Comment: So does it mean I just need to prove both sides equate to 0 to show it passes through the origin?

Comment: Yes. More precisely, you're proving both sides are equal. For example, if you were trying to show that the point $(6,-22)$ is on the curve, you would have to show that plugging $x=6$ and $y=-22$ into the equation makes both sides equal $-22$. What I mean is that the value that both sides will equal depends on the point.